# GtkTreeView current row text underline

Tags: css, gtk, gtk3, gtktreeview

How can I underline only text (not entire row) in GtkTreeView?

```
GtkTreeView row:selected
{
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ffffff;
}
```

gives me this:

[image: Imgur]

when I want this:

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `hexpand` property of the label to false, and the `halign` property to something other than "fill"; (note these are properties in your code, not in CSS) or you could use `<u>Wi-Fi</u>` as the text of your label and turn on the `use-markup` property.